# Getting ido to work with evil in emacs

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, ido

I'm trying to get ido to work with evil ex commands (such as `:vsp ...` or `:b ...`), but it doesn't seem to be working automatically.  Currently I have:

```
(require 'ido)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode t)
(use-package ido-ubiquitous
  :ensure ido-ubiquitous
  :demand ido-ubiquitous
  :init
  (progn
    (ido-ubiquitous-mode 1)))
```

And then later I require evil:

```
(use-package evil
  :ensure evil
  :config
  (progn
    (evil-mode 1)
    ;; ....
  ))
```

As a work around I can use stuff like `(define-key evil-ex-map "e " 'ido-find-file)` and some custom ones for the splits but this isn't ideal.  Why doesn't the above work automatically?

I'm using the graphical version of Emacs 25.0.50.1

Comment: [from the ido-ubiquitous source](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/blob/bleeding-edge/ido-ubiquitous.el): "ido-ubiquitous is here to enable ido-style completion for (almost) every function that uses the standard completion function 'completing-read'". Evil uses completion-at-point rather than completing-read for ex-commands, probably to better control how things work in ex. If this is the extend of your question I'll post this as an answer, but I imagine you're looking for a solution as well.

Comment: @GordonGustafson Thanks.  I have a work around which makes the few ex commands I use frequently behave as I'd like, so I don't think I need another solution.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @SL2, would very much like to know what your workaround was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**from the ido-ubiquitous source**](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous/blob/bleeding-edge/ido-ubiquitous.el):

> ido-ubiquitous is here to enable ido-style completion for (almost)
>   every function that uses the standard completion function
>   'completing-read'

Evil uses `completion-at-point` rather than `completing-read` for ex commands. While `completion-at-point` merely tries to complete what's before the cursor, `completing-read` brings up its own prompt with its own behavior. Since evil adds its own keybindings in the ex prompt, using `completing-read` for ex commands isn't feasible.